# Braintree - How can I transfer funds to another customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree-rails

Hello I am integrating braintree in my rails app. I have two roles and one of them pays the amount with a sale transaction to the merchant account. But my scenario is like that I have to then give some of the share to another user for which of course I need to transfer funds to that user account.

Can anyone tell me how am I suppose to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called the [Braintree Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products-and-features/marketplace) that might solve your problem. The only issue here is that your other user would need to be signed up as a sub-merchant.